# Can flyway handle migration after validating the DB?

Tags: flyway

Can flyway do a validation check on the database before doing migration?

**Scenario 1**

For eg: I am trying to execute flyway on an existing DB. I have already inserted few users to my db_users table.

But my sql script has create statement for db_users table and also the insert statements for all users including the ones which is already inserted.

I can do and IF NOT_EXISTS check before creating a table, but will be difficult to do a check before each insert.

**Scenario 2**

I have migrated scripts V1, V2, V3 in my database. I modify the script V2 and make some changes. Will flyway identify this change next time I start the application.

**Scenario 3**

I have a create table statement in the V2 sql script. But after starting my application, I deleted the table manually. Next time when I start the application, will Flyway recognise the DB change and execute V2 again?

Could you please let me know how I can handle these situation in Flyway.

Comment: You'll get into trouble with hash validation if you modify the V2 script after it's been run against a schema.  Consider creating a V4 script which makes your changes.  Even if it's wordy, you'll be working with rather than against the tool.

Answer (score 1):

Everything you are asking is in the docs. If they are not clear enough, please let me know how they could be improved. If you could not find the info, let me know why.

Scenario 1: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/existing

Scenario 2: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/command/validate

Scenario 3: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/faq#outside-changes

Comment: For Scenario 3, does Flyway catch external changes in the validate step? We are looking for something that can ensure that our resulting schema matches. Your link says we shouldn't make external changes, and we agree. Thing is, can we assure that they have not?